# wordpress (WPMU) new site not inserting in wp_blogs table

Tags: php, wordpress, wpmu

In wordpress suddenly I am facing one issue that while creating new subsite then all subsite tables are creating properly but new site entry is not inserting in "wp_blogs" table that's why I am not able to see new in admin site menu.

Can anyone tell what could be the reason? I think wordpress automatically insert the entry in wp_blogs while creating new site. But it's not working for me.. How to debug? or if anyone have face such kind of issue then please share your experience

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable database error display via `$wpdb->show_errors()`
2. Check what query is being formed and run via `$wpdb->last_query`